negative OpAmp output with LM7705 on the ground pin
Can someone help me understand why I'm measuring -0.23V on the output of the MAX44285 OpAmp when I add the LM7705 -0.23V supply to the ground as shown? According to this reference design LINK, it seems like the way to go to accurately measure low voltages. I'm not an expert in this area, but I'm suspecting the OpAmp I'm using is the issue?
When I remove the LM7705 and connect the OpAmp directly to ground, I get the proper readings in the ADC (looks like plot 1), but it is non-linear at low voltages.
Insertion of the LM7705 causes the output of the OpAmp to start increasing from -0.23v to 0v at low voltage inputs, something like plot 2. The ADC cant read the negative volts, so I was expecting/hoping for the OpAmp to start output at 0v.
I appreciate the help to understand what is going on!


The MAX44285 is not a standard op-amp, it provides the feedback resistors inside the package. It works as expected in your circuit, because it references the output to it's negative supply pin due to the internal feedback resistors.
The link you provided that adds the negative supply only works with a standard op-amp when the feedback components are external and can be referenced to 0V instead of newly generated negative supply.
With MAX44285, the feedback is in reference to the negative supply pin so the output is too, so that's why output is negative compared to your 0V.
What you could do is to add a DC bias to the output with resistors before measuring with the ADC, but as you saw, it won't fix the problem of MAX44285 output being non-linear with low output voltages.

Makes sense. Thank you!
